# Why is my <p> fonts black?

Tags: html, css, notepad++

***My paragraph is black even though I specified a*** (supported) **color. 

Where seems to be the error? 

How do I fix it? 

Thanks!**

HTML code:

```
<div id="welcome">
    <p>
    <center><b><em> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh</em></b></center>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background-color:#2e4053;
}

p{
    font-family:Noto Sans Sinhala;
    src: url('Font/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf');
    font-style:     ;
    font-size:50%;
    color:#f4f6f7 !important;
    font-weight:500;
}
```

Comment: Why the use of "font-style:     ;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `<center>` is a block level element.  You can't have a block level element inside of a `<p>` (paragraph) element.  The reason for this is a nuanced alternative syntax for paragraph tags that excludes the closing tag.  You can have a paragraph tag written like the following and have it validate:

```
<p>This is a paragraph element that doesn't have a closing tag.
<p>Here's another.  This is all valid HTML.
```

The definition of this functionality can be found [in the w3c documnetation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-p-element) under the "Tag omission in text/html" part.   Because of this, generally when a paragraph tag hits a block level element, it assumes that the tag has closed.  Your HTML then becomes this:

```
<div id="welcome">
    <p></p>
    <center><b><em> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh</em></b></center>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

As you can see, this means that your `em` is not technically inside a paragraph. It's recomended that you instead use the `text-align:center` CSS property as [`<center>` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center).

```css
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background-color:#2e4053;
}

p{
    font-family:Noto Sans Sinhala;
    src: url('Font/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf');
    font-style:     ;
    font-size:50%;
    text-align: center;
    color:#f4f6f7;
    font-weight:500;
}
```

```html
<div id="welcome">
    <p>
        <b><em> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh</em></b>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! The CSS Style rule worked. Keep up the good work! 

Answer (score -1):

you can do this in 2 ways.
1.try removing the id=welcome.
or 
call the id=welcome in css and specified a (supported) color.
HTML code:

```
<div>
    <p>
         <center><b><em> AaBbCcDdEeFfGgHh</em></b></center>
    </p>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background: linear-gradient(left,#2e4053,#212F3C);
    background-color:#2e4053;
```

}

```
 p {
    font-family:Noto Sans Sinhala;
    src: url('Font/NotoSansSinhala-Regular.ttf');
    font-style:     ;
    font-size:50%;
    color:#f4f6f7 !important;
    font-weight:500;
```

Comment: It is a good idea to check one's answer before posting it, so it works...which this doesn't